# Symfony & Git: Best practice for multiple websites

Tags: git, symfony, git-submodules, symfony-3.1

I'm developing a symfony 3 application to run websites for concert/ booking agencies. Now I wonder what would be the best practice to configure Git when I keep developing the app while I'm running multiple websites for different clients? The custom files that differ from project to project are located in different places and levels in the structure given by Symfony. In the diagram below they are labeled orange:

[image: Symfony Project with custom files]

So what would be the best approach to handle this with Git? Should I work with a repo for the core (excl. the custom files/ folders) and an additional repo for each client which uses the core repo as submodule?
For the workflow the ideal conception would be, when I'd be able to work with the client repo and modify the core basis in order that new core features would be automatically applied to the other client websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to move the custom views originally located in the FrontBundle to `app/Resources` and change the references in the Controllers. In this way it´s possible versionize the core in its own repo (marked green) and include it as a submodule in the repos of each client project.

[image: New structure including submodule]

Even though this solution works for now I´m curious what´s your approach to manage such problems.

Comment: I'm getting into this very topic at the moment. Thank you so much for your question and answer. There are very few spots on the Internet about this and your answers is one of them.

How do you approach this now?

Comment: I have stayed with this approach. My requirements are met without any compromises and I have not encountered any alternative since then.